# ULdepth does not change space in equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, ulem, underline

I am trying to underline a result within an equation environment. The result contains a Matrix. I use the `ulem` package with `uline`.

How can I add more space between my matrix and the line?

I tried ULdepth which did not change the space between my matrix and the line.

Code example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl) 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{ulem} 
\setlength{\ULdepth}{20pt}

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation*} 
\uline{A \cdot B =%
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
6 & -12 \\
14 & 4    
\end{bmatrix*}} 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Matrix with uline]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always `\addstackgap` befor ethe `\uline`.  Here, macrofied as

`\Uline[<extra depth>]{<math content>}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine} 
\usepackage{ulem} 
\setlength{\ULdepth}{20pt}
\newcommand\Uline[2][3pt]{\uline{\ensurestackMath{\addstackgap[#1]{#2}}}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation*} 
\Uline{A \cdot B =%
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
6 & -12 \\
14 & 4    
\end{bmatrix*}}\qquad
\Uline[6pt]{A \cdot B =%
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
6 & -12 \\
14 & 4    
\end{bmatrix*}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the argument to `\Uline` will be set in `\textstyle` unless `\displaystyle` is explicitly invoked (though I could automate it, were it vital to the answer).

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{ulem} 
\setlength\ULdepth{20pt}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation*} 
\uline{A \cdot B =
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        6 & -12 \\
        14 & 4    
\end{bmatrix*}\rule[-15pt]{0pt}{0pt}} 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `\uline` is

```latex
% ulem.sty, line 43:
\def\uline{\relax \ifmmode\expandafter\underline 
           \else \bgroup\expandafter\ULset\fi}
```

Thus you see that in math mode, the result is the same as for `\underline`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}c@{}}
A\cdot B=
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  6 & -12 \\
  14 & 4
  \end{bmatrix*}
\\
\addlinespace[5pt]
\midrule
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]